# REG ADD with spaces within FORFILES command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to automate setting the App Compatibility flags for numerous EXE files we use.  I can get the forfiles command to pull up all of the EXE full paths with no problem.  The issue is passing that information to the REG ADD command with the space.  What am I missing here?  I've tried several sets of double quotes as well as single quotes but nothing is working right.  What's the correct syntax for this command to work?  If it can be done as shown below that's great.  If it has to be done a different way, that's ok too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SET Key="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Window NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"
SET Command="'REG ADD' "%KEY%" /v @PATH /t "REG_SZ" /d "RUNASADMIN""

forfiles /p D:\<DIR> /S /m *.exe -c "cmd %Command%"
```

Comment: And I realize the single quotes are probably not necessary around REG ADD.  I didn't realize I still had them in there when I copied this from where I was working.  Shame on me for not proofing better.

Comment: quotes can be escapes with `0x22`  - http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: Quotes aside, shouldn't you be doing `forfiles /p D:\<DIR> /S /m *.exe -c "cmd /c %Command%"`?  doing just `cmd` will just launch a command shell and not execute your command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```dos
SET "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"
for /r "d:\<dir>" %%a in ("*.exe") do ( 
    reg add "%Key%" /t REG_SZ /v "%%~fa" /d RUNASADMIN
)
```

Comment: Beautiful.  I think that worked.  I'll check the files to be sure, but it said it completed successfully.

Checked the files that should've been set, but the flags for Compatibility weren't set when looking at the Properties in Windows.  Could I be going to the wrong Registry key?

Comment: It passes the correct files to the REG ADD command, but the settings are not showing up in the Registry.

My excitement was short-lived, lol

Comment: @ThatDevilTech, I copied and pasted your key without even read it. There was a `s` missing in `Windows NT`

Comment: Looks like it worked correctly this time around.  Thanks again.